# Unselecting Dropdown Checklist from dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

I am trying to select/unselect items individually in a Dropdown Checklist plugin for jQuery.

The plugin is : [dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com)

I have tried this but it doesn't work :

```
$('#mylist option').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('selected',false);
    $('#mylist'+i).attr('selected',false);
}
```

Where i is an incremented integer.
I have also tried with removeAttr before attr...

Anyone has an idea how to accomplish this ?

I have tried to implement the following, to no avail :

> Dropdown CheckList generates two basic components that are inserted into the document. There is a control wrapper which is positioned in place of the original selector and acts like the  item on the page. And there is the drop-down wrapper which is only visible when the control wrapper is 'open' and is positioned under the control.
>
> Both of these items are assigned an
>   id, which you can use in other jQuery
>   processing to locate and alter the
>   items.
>
> Control Wrapper
>       The control wrapper has a generated id of the form "ddcl-XXX",
>   where the XXX is either 1) the
>   assigned id of underlying , or
>   2) an incrementing counter when the
>    has no id assigned. 
>   Drop-down Wrapper
>       The drop-down wrapper has a generated id of the form
>   "ddcl-XXX-ddw", where the XXX matches
>   the XXX of the control wrapper.
>
> These ids must be unique and Dropdown
>   CheckList assumes no other elements on
>   the page have an id that conflicts.

Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

Actually, you need to destroy the component.

See below :

```
$('#mylist').dropdownchecklist('destroy');
 $('#mylist option').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('selected',false);
 });
$("#mylist").dropdownchecklist();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

$("#mylist").val("");
$("#mylist").dropdownchecklist("refresh");

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that `i` was not defined, you need to initiate it in the function you pass to the each loop:

```
$('#mylist option').each(function(i, el){
    $(this).attr('selected',true);
    $('#mylist'+i).attr('selected',true);
});
```

BTW, will `#mylist1` & `#mylist2` actually exist? Why are you trying to check them if they are lists, not options?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. i is incremented as I said. I omitted it to clarify the code. #mylist+i refers to the control wrapper as specified in the quoted documentation (ddcl-XXX).

Comment: Ah. I see. If you are trying to deselect them why are you setting `$(this).attr('selected')` to true? It should be false to deselect them.

Comment: Yeah right... I'm sorry, I was testing... let me change this :)